# Find Space around logo and alert if any pageitem present in that space

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to find any object that is near or around the logo.

By adding 1/3 of the logo height to its bounds and comparing all the pageitems with the bounds.

How to skip the parent object of the graphic link? for the below script
Here is the script:

```
function _clear_space_around_logo(){  
    var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
    var myPages = myDoc.pages;
    for(var a=0;a<myPages.length;a++){
        var myGraphics = myPages[a].allGraphics;
        for(var b=0;b<myGraphics.length;b++){
            if(myGraphics[b].itemLink != null){
                if(myGraphics[b].itemLink.name.search(/Logo/i)>0){
                    if(myGraphics[b].parent.rotationAngle == 0 || myGraphics[b].parent.rotationAngle == 180){
                        var geo0 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[0];
                        var geo1 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[1];
                        var geo2 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[2];
                        var geo3 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[3];
                        var requiredHeight = (geo2-geo0)/3;
                        var reuqiredGeo0 = geo0-requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo1 = geo1-requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo2 = geo2+requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo3 = geo3+requiredHeight;
                    }
                    else{
                        var geo0 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[0];
                        var geo1 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[1];
                        var geo2 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[2];
                        var geo3 = myGraphics[b].geometricBounds[3];
                        var requiredHeight = (geo3-geo1)/3;
                        var reuqiredGeo0 = geo0-requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo1 = geo1-requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo2 = geo2+requiredHeight;
                        var reuqiredGeo3 = geo3+requiredHeight;
                    }
                    var myPagesItems = myPages[a].allPageItems;
                    for(var c=0;c<myPagesItems.length;c++){
                        if(myPagesItems[c].itemLayer.visible == true && myPagesItems[c].visible == true){
                            var itemGeo0 = myPagesItems[c].geometricBounds[0];
                            var itemGeo1 = myPagesItems[c].geometricBounds[1];
                            var itemGeo2 = myPagesItems[c].geometricBounds[2];
                            var itemGeo3 = myPagesItems[c].geometricBounds[3];
                            
                            if(itemGeo0>myPages[a].bounds[0] && itemGeo1>myPages[a].bounds[1]&&
                                itemGeo2<myPages[a].bounds[2] && itemGeo3<myPages[a].bounds[3]){
                                if(itemGeo2 > reuqiredGeo0 && itemGeo3 > reuqiredGeo1 &&
                                    itemGeo0 < reuqiredGeo2 && itemGeo1 < reuqiredGeo3){
                                    if(myPagesItems[c].constructor.name != "Group"){
                                        try{
                                            if(myPagesItems[c].itemLink.name.search(/Logo/i)==-1){
                                                alert(myPages[a].name);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch(e){
                                            alert(myPages[a].name);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: _to find any object_ — do you mean to select the graphic objects? or to remove them? or to add to a some array? Basically you can get a pasted graphic from `myPagesItems[c]` as `var myGraphic = myPagesItems[c].graphics[0]`.

Comment: Hi, Ashwin, are you here?

Comment: Hi, @YuriKhristich sorry for the delay.

I got my answer in the community post. Please find the link below:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/find-space-around-logo-and-alert-if-any-pageitem-present-in-that-space/m-p/12842231#M471160

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@brianp311**

Store the id of the parent container and skip it on your check.

var pid = myGraphics[b].parent.id;

Then...

if (myPageItems[c].id == pid) continue;